# How can I change fixed width of container in bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

When we use div `container` class in bootstrap we have got fixed size of padding on our web pages. I want to change it without writing any *media query(CSS)*. How can I do it when I used bootstrap CSS CDN?

Comment: Define same class in your style sheet or page

Comment: if you are using bootstrap-4, then add p-0 class in container element.

Comment: If you want to override Bootstrap write css code that target these classes in another css file.

Comment: I didn't got your answer!

Comment: What do you mean withˋstyle tag´. Maybe you need to edit your question with some example.

Comment: yeah Its about in div tag style attribute. does it possible without use style attribute in div tag that class="container" used?

Comment: include the bootstrap file in the top and your custom.css in the bottom

Comment: I don't want to add any custom.css file to my html file. simply I want to change the fixed with of class container without use any CSS. (Only from bootstrap when using CDN)

Comment: @Binoj123, if you want to use the CDN you can't change the container without any custom css applied.